# Inheritance : Base class method which returns an instance of itself

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, subclass

My base class has a method that returns an instance of itself. When I write my subclass, is there any way to make this instance an instance of my subclass instead of the base class, without modifying the code of the base class or rewriting the whole base class method into my subclass method ?

Example :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def add(self):
        self.x += 2
    def new(self,z):
        n = A(z)
        return n

class B(A):
    def __init__self():
        A.__init__(self,x)
```

Here if I do :

```
a = B(10)
b = a.new(4)
```

Then b will be an instance of A and not an instance of B like I want it to be. 
In this simple example I could just override the method in the B class but in my program I don't want to, it would just ruin portability because I have no control over the base class since it is part of another package.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Make it a class method:

```
@classmethod
def new(cls, z):
    return cls(z)
```

Comment: I can't, as I said I can't modify the code of the Base class :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't spot that. Then: no.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, instead of:

```
def new(self,z):
    n = A(z)
    return n
```

You'd have:

```
def new(self, z):
    n = self.__class__(z)
    return n
```

That way, you're using the class of in instance the method was called on, instead of hardcoding the class that you're creating a new instance of.

However, since you've mentioned you can't modify the base class, you have two options:

1. Override the method in the derived class
2. Monkey patch the base class
3. Request whoever maintains the base class to make this change for you

You've said you don't want to override it because it's bad for portability. I would argue that this isn't true - if the base class is likely to be updated such that the behaviour of it's public API changes, it's already bad for portability because who knows what breaking changes it might introduce. If the behaviour is going to stay consistent (even if the implementation changes) it should be safe to override.

The other option is to monkey patch the base class. This would have the same problems as overriding in the base class, the difference is that other subclasses would get the behaviour too - not just those that inherit from B.

You'd monkey patch like this (outside of a class definition):

```
def new_new(self, z):
    n = self.__class__(z)
    return n

A.new = new_new
```

Comment: I would, unfortunately as I said I have no control over the base class so I can't rewrite it :(

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I think we need an explanation of why overriding would be bad for portability in your case, since I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Well if the method changes in the base class in a new revision, it would be messy because then my override method would be out of date. So that makes my override method linked to a particular revision of the base class module. Hence bad for portability. That's why I wanted to know if there was any way to do it without messing with the method itself but from what you said it doesn't possible.

Comment: @Nolhian If the base class method changes, isn't it also going to be messy *everywhere that relies on that base class*?

Comment: If it is only a update in the method that doesn't affect the result, like a security update, catching an additionnal exception or whatever, it won't be messy everywhere that relies on the base class. It would just be my code that would be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__class__`:

> ```
> n = self.__class__(z)
> return n
> ```

...

@jonrsharpe's answer is better